# Regarding NSPredicate and NSMutableArray deep copy

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

I am trying to copy NSMutableArray which is based of my Registration NSMutableArray Class and trying to filter a boolean. The concern is, since the nsmutablearray is from the class, each time I try to `alloc and initwitharray:[self person] man];` where man is a nsmutablearray it doesn't allow me to do it. Is this functionality only localized or can be globally utilized as well? Or am I missing something here?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the entire statement that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that "man" is declared as a property of "[self person]". i.e. in the header of the class that [self person] is an instance of,

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *man;
```

and in the implementation:

```
@synthesize man;
```

Comment: its already done in the Person class but not in Registration class, i thought its not required since I am already allocating and retaining the class object itself. Thanks